# how to insert a rectangle with the text on the border in power point?

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint

What I want to do is to insert a rectangle (actually I want a rounded rectangle? )

But different from normal one, I want the text to be on the boarder, I tried right click the rectangle and select format but still can't find it.

Could some body tell how to do it?

Sorry my reputation is not enough, I can't upload the picture. Just draw something like below: Please ignore the dotted lines.

```
----  Text -------------
|                      |  
|                      |
|                      |
|______________________|
```

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to superuser, Sean!
I'm afraid PowerPoint doesn't give you that level of control on the rectangle objects, but it is not hard to get the effect you're looking for by combining two objects:

1. Create your rounded rectangle.
2. Next click the "Text Box" button (the one that looks like a piece of lined paper with an A at the top).
3. Click on the page anywhere *outside* of your rectangle (make sure not to click near the border).
4. Type your text.
5. Now move the text box to align it with the rectangle border.
6. To make it more readable, add a shape fill to the text box that matches your background. This will hide the border behind the text. If there is still a line covering your text, move the text box to the front ("Arrange"->"Bring to front")
7. If you want to make sure they are always together, select both objects (rect + text) and click "Group" ("Arrange" -> "Group")

[image: example image]